# Javascript test with regex for 7 signs and 2 numbers

Tags: javascript

I want to do a password check in Javascript for 7 signs and the password must contain 2 numbers. I have this code, but this will test only for 1 number. How to test for 2 numbers...

```
var re = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).{7,}/; 
if (!re.test(password.value)) {
    alert('Passwords must contain at least one number, one lowercase and one uppercase letter.  Please try again');
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force at least 2 (not necessarily next to each other) digits you can do this:

```
/^(?=.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).{7,}$/
```

If you want exactly 2 (not necessarily next to each other) digits it gets slightly more complicated:

```
/^(?=[^\d]*\d[^\d]*\d[^\d]*$)(?=.*[a-z]).{7,}$/
```

DEMO: http://regex101.com/r/iB0tE6

NOTE: I also anchored your regexes for you. Otherwise, a longer password which contains a sequence of 7 fit characters would still match.

Comment: is the regex in PHP the same?

Comment: @JilcoTigchelaar Yes, it's the same in PHP, you can check in the demo i mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

The `\d` only checks for a single digit. You can check for two numbers specifically by adding a second instance of the digit check: `\d\d`. Alternatively, if you want to check for at least 2 numbers, you should use `\d\d+`, which will check for 1 digit, and then 1 or more digits.

Comment: This would enforce two *consecutive* digits, something that is usually not required for passwords.